# Как правильно построить иерархию классов в Java?

Tags: java

Пишу программу, которая импортирует ексель файл в базу данных. Там есть определенная таблица с теми же полями, что и в ексель файле. Хотелось узнать как правильнее устроить иерархию классов.

Иерархия, которая используется сейчас:

1. Main
2. DatabaseConnection (создает соединение с базой)
3. Configs (содержит данные про базу, которые используются для подключения)
4. Handler (выполняет загрузку)

Использую JDBC драйвер дял работы с базой и Apache POI для работы с ексель.

**Class Main**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Handler handler = null;

        try {
            handler = new Handler();

            Directory directory = new Directory("путь к директории");
            ArrayList<String> defunctFiles = new ArrayList<>();

            // Файлы, которые были загружены без ошибок
            int uploadedFiles = 0;

            // Считает время работы программы
            Timer timer = new Timer();

            System.out.println("Uploading...");

            // Индикатор загрузки
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

            timer.start();
            for (int i = 0; i < directory.getNumberOfFiles(); i++) {
                try {
                    handler.uploadFile(directory.getDirectoryFile(i));
                    uploadedFiles++;
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    defunctFiles.add(directory.getDirectoryFile(i).getName() + "(" + exception.getMessage() + ")");
                }

                progressBar.step(i, directory.getNumberOfFiles() - 1);
            }
            timer.end();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Uploaded files: " + uploadedFiles + "\\" + directory.getNumberOfFiles());

            if (defunctFiles.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("\nDefunct files: ");
                showDefunctFiles(defunctFiles);
            }

            System.out.println("\nTime: " + timer.getTimeInSeconds() + "s");
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            System.out.println("Failed connection");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed driver registration");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Progress is greater than set");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Функция создания вывода деффектных файлов
     */
    private static void showDefunctFiles(ArrayList<String> files) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(files.get(i));

            if (i < files.size() - 1) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Class DatabaseConnection**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnection extends Configs {
    /**
     * Функция создания соединения с базой данных
     *
     * @return возвраащет обьект Connection
     */
    public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(driver);

        // DriverManager управляет списком драйверов БД. Каждой запрос на соединение требует соответствующего драйвера. Первое совпадение даёт нам соединение.
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, password);

    }
}
```

**Class Handler**

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Handler {
    /**
     * Поле соединение (Connection)
     * Этот интерфейс обеспечивает методами для работы с БД.
     * Все взаимодействия с БД происходят исключительно через Connection.
     */
    private final Connection connection;

    /**
     * Конструктор - создание нового объекта
     * Создание  соединения с базой данных
     */
    public Handler() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        connection = new DatabaseConnection().createConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Функция загрузки файлов Excel в базу данных
     *
     * @param file - файл, который нужно загрузить
     */
    public void uploadFile(final File file) throws Exception {
        String sql = "insert into \"название таблицы\"(\"названия колонок\") values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        String sheetName = "название таблицы";

        //Для подтверждения SQL-запросов мы используем объекты, созданные с использованием этого интерфейса.
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        //Класс чтения и записи файлов Microsoft Excel в формате .xlsx
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file.getPath()));

        //Класс может создавать таблицы Excel и позволяет форматировать стиль листа и данные листа.
        Sheet sheet = findSheetByName(workbook, sheetName);

        //Проверка на null-значение листа. Если null, то таблица не найдена
        if (sheet == null) {
            //Выброс исключения
            throw new Exception();
        }

        //Класс представляет возможность перебрать все элементы в коллекции без вникания во внутреннюю структуру и устройство коллекций.
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        rowIterator.next();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            //Класс включает свойства и методы работы со строками, создания ячеек в строке и т.д.
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            cellIterator.next();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                //Ячейки электронной таблицы используются для размещения информации.
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                //Класс позволяет получить тип информации, которая содержится в ячейке
                CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();

                //Строковое представление информации, находящейся в ячейке
                String cellValue = cellType.equals(CellType.STRING) ? cell.getStringCellValue() : String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());

                //Проверка содержит ли переменная значенние(не пустое)*/
                if (!cellValue.isEmpty() && !cellValue.equals(" ")) {

                    //Проверка типа информации, которая содержиться в даной ячейке
                    if (cellType.equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {

                        //Запись значений в базу даных
                        preparedStatement.setDouble(cell.getColumnIndex(), Double.parseDouble(cellValue));
                    } else if (cellType.equals(CellType.STRING)) {
                        preparedStatement.setString(cell.getColumnIndex(), cellValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            preparedStatement.setString(11, file.getName());

            //Выполняет такие SQL-команды, как INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE и возвращает количество измененных строк
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }

        //Закрываются потоки
        preparedStatement.close();
        workbook.close();
    }

    /**
     * Функция поиска листа в файле Excel по имени
     *
     * @return возвращает страницу или null
     */
    private Sheet findSheetByName(XSSFWorkbook workbook, String sheetName) {
        //Прохождение циклом по всем таблицам файла и поиск нужной
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            if (workbook.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName().equalsIgnoreCase(sheetName)) {
                return workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Class Configs**

```
public class Configs {
    protected static final String host = "";
    protected static final String port = "";

    protected static final String user = "";
    protected static final String userName = "";
    protected static final String password = "";

    protected static final String name = "";

    protected static final String connectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + name;
    protected static final String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
}
```

Comment: сложно оценить ваш код, не глядя на ваш код... добавляйте код и порефакторим коллективным разумом))

Comment: Я добавил основные классы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал сделать рефакторинг, поскольку у вас нет тестов, возможно где-то ошибся. Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Directory directory = new Directory("путь к директории");
            
            List<String> defunctFiles = new ArrayList<>();   
            
            print("Uploading...");
    
            // Индикатор загрузки
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
            
            Handler handler = new Handler();
    
            // Считает время работы программы  
            long start = System.nanoTime();
    
            for (int i = 0; i < directory.getNumberOfFiles(); i++) {
                try {
                    handler.uploadFile(directory.getDirectoryFile(i));
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    defunctFiles.add(directory.getDirectoryFile(i).getName() + "(" + e.getMessage() + ")");
                }
                progressBar.step(i, directory.getNumberOfFiles() - 1);
            }
            long leadTime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert((System.nanoTime() - start), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            
            print("Uploaded files: " + (directory.getNumberOfFiles()-defunctFiles.size()) + "\\" + directory.getNumberOfFiles());
    
            showDefunctFiles(defunctFiles);
            
            print("Time: " + leadTime + " sec");
        }
    
        /**
         * Функция создания вывода деффектных файлов
         */
        private static void showDefunctFiles(Collection <String> files) {
            if (!files.isEmpty()) print("Defunct files: ", files.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
        
        public static void print(Object ... args) {
            for (Object arg : args) System.out.println(arg);
        }
    
    }
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Handler {

    /**
     * Функция загрузки файлов Excel в базу данных
     *
     * @param file - файл, который нужно загрузить
     */
    public void uploadFile(final File file) {

        String sheetName = "название таблицы";

        try (DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection()) {
            try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)) {
                //Класс представляет возможность перебрать все элементы в коллекции без вникания во внутреннюю структуру и устройство коллекций.
                Iterator <Row> rowIterator = getIterator(workbook.getSheet(sheetName));
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = getIterator(rowIterator.next());
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        //Ячейки электронной таблицы используются для размещения информации.
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        //Проверка типа информации, которая содержиться в даной ячейке, запись значений в базу даных
                        if (CellType.NUMERIC.equals(cell.getCellType())) {
                            connection.set(cell.getColumnIndex(),cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else if (CellType.STRING.equals(cell.getCellType())) {
                            String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                            if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) connection.set(cell.getColumnIndex(), cellValue);
                        }
                    }
                    connection.set(11, file.getName()).update();
                }
            } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private <T> Iterator<T> getIterator(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        if (iterator.hasNext()) iterator.next();
        return iterator;
    }

}
    
    import java.io.Closeable;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    
    public class DatabaseConnection implements Closeable {
    
        private static final String HOST = "";
        private static final String PORT = "";
        private static final String USERNAME = "";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "";
        private static final String DB_NAME = "";
        private static final String DB_DRIVER_NAME = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        private static final String SQL = "insert into \"название таблицы\"(\"названия колонок\") values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    
        private static final Connection CONNECTION;
    
        private final PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    
        static {
            try {
                Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_NAME);
                CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/" + DB_NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
        public DatabaseConnection() {
            try {
                //Для подтверждения SQL-запросов мы используем объекты, созданные с использованием этого интерфейса.
                this.preparedStatement = CONNECTION.prepareStatement(SQL);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
        public DatabaseConnection update() {
            try {
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                return this;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
        public DatabaseConnection set(int parameterIndex, double x) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.setDouble(parameterIndex, x);
                return this;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        
        public DatabaseConnection set(int parameterIndex, String x) {
            try {
                preparedStatement.setString(parameterIndex, x);
                return this;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас буду разбираться)

Comment: @Vlad не за что. если возникают какие-либо вопросы- задавайте. но в целом я бы паорекомендовал вам использовать какую-то орм (можно начато с орм лайт, наприимер, она наряду с кастомными поддерживает стандартные аннотации, что в дальнейшем облегчит работу с спринг дата). jdbc в чистом виде я за последние 5-7 лет видел на реальном проекте всего 1 раз...

Comment: я сидел разбирался и не могу понять зачем нужно в методах set, update в классе DatabaseConnection возвращать обьект? Спасибо)

Comment: @Vlad в целом вы можете этого не делать (это не обязательно). просто зачастую в таких случаях необходимо вызвать последовательно несколько методов объекта (в нашем случае DatabaseConnection), как это сделано в этой строке кода: connection.set(11, file.getName()).update(); Т.е. в одной строке кода одновременно вызыветсяметод set и тут же у возвращаемого значения (объекта DatabaseConnection) метод update.

Comment: Аааааа, все, я понял. Спасибо ещё раз огромное!!!)